# Parking brake left on

Tags: ford, toyota, battery, braking, driving

So I went to move  my car this morning around two blocks from my house. My parking brake was on and I didn’t know. When I parked I realized it was on the whole time. It was driven for 2 block going 5 miles per hour 10 at the most but I just want to know if there was any damage for that small amount of driving and slow speed. It’s a 2019 Dodge Charger

Comment: Been asked before, search on here.

Answer (score 1):

The short of this is yes, you MAY have damaged your rear brakes.  The only way to tell for sure is to have them inspected by a mechanic (or if you know what you are doing, inspect them yourself) and determine if there has been damage, what is the extent of it, and what (if anything) needs to be fixed.

In some cases the damage is just premature wear of the pads and rotors or drum.  In other cases the pads can become "glazed" due to the heat and will no longer brake properly.  The rotors or drums can also be damaged by heat and warp or even crack.

It's also possible that the brake calipers or cylinders have "baked" and now have solidified brake fluid in them. In this case they will need to be rebuilt or replaced.

I know that's a lot of "ifs" but any or all of this is possible.  It just depends.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah it is a lot of ifs but it makes sense but I don’t think or know if driving around the block at 10 miles an hour or slower will damage it like that.

Comment: if the brakes still seem to work the same as before they're probably fine.